# how can I add a vertical scrollbar to a portion of a div, while keeping both scrollbar controls visible?

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a div divided into 2 sections (top and bottom), and I am trying to make the bottom section vertically scrollable.  The entire div has a fixed size.  The bottom section's content is dynamic and I don't know how much will be there (there potentially could be hundreds of lines of text).

The best I have been able to do is this:  http://jsfiddle.net/2zdx251b/

```
#main {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 240px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#want-to-scroll {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This is close, but I can't scroll down far enough to see the end of the bottom content, and I can't see the bottom "arrow" of the scrollbar.  If you look at the fiddle, it will be obvious that the scrollbar isn't working exactly right.

How can I view the entire bottom section (i.e. all content when I scroll down, and the both the top and bottom arrows of the scrollbar at all times)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is `height: 100%;` takes into account the entire height of the container element `#main`.

If you're comfortable using [CSS `flex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/), then this can be cleaned up by adding flexible columns, as in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zdx251b/3/).

```
#main {
    /* ... */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Note, the `hr` element needed to styled to include `width: 100%;` in order to accommodate this.